# OpenCV findContours, how to check colors on both sides

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an `Mat` object derived using the canny edge detectors, I extracted contours from such image using the `findContours` function. Now what I'd like to do for each  of such contours would be somehow check the colour on both sides.

For the "colour" bit I've discretized HSI color space, however I'm very confused on how I could "pick the colours" in both sides given a contour.

Is there a way to easily do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the image that you apply the Canny edge detector to do this. Take the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of that image. Gradient is a vector. As shown in the wiki page image (shown below), the gradient points in the direction of the greatest rate of increase. If you take the negative gradient, then it points in the direction of the greatest rate of decrease. Therefore, if you sample the gradient of the image at contour points, positive and negative gradients at those points should point to the regions either side of contour points. So, you can sample points along these directions to get an idea about the colors you want.

Image gradient:

[image: gradient]

Sample python code shows how this is done for the simple image shown below. It uses Sobel to calculate the gradient.

Input image:

[image: original image]

Canny edges and sampled points:

Green: point on contour

Red: point in the positive gradient direction

Blue: point in the negative gradient direction

[image: points]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('grad.png', 0)

dx = cv2.Sobel(im, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
dy = cv2.Sobel(im, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
edge = cv2.Canny(im, 64, 192)

dx = dx / np.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + 0.01)
dy = dy / np.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + 0.01)

r = 20

y, x = np.nonzero(edge)

pos1 = (np.int32(x[128]+r*dx[y[128], x[128]]), np.int32(y[128]+r*dy[y[128], x[128]]))
pos2 = (np.int32(x[128]-r*dx[y[128], x[128]]), np.int32(y[128]-r*dy[y[128], x[128]]))

im2 = cv2.cvtColor(edge, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.circle(im2, pos1, 10, (255, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.circle(im2, pos2, 10, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.circle(im2, (x[128], y[128]), 10, (0, 255, 0), 1)

plt.imshow(im2)
```